# Perl: difficulty understanding how to access list of list passed by reference?

Tags: perl, reference, pass-by-reference

This is a perl function I wrote for a genetic/evolution algorithm for comparing data from various texts documents. I'm trying to get the reproduction part down:

My function calls `get_2d_agree_groups` which returns a "list of list" by reference which I then need to further access, modify, remove or add to the inner lists as needed. `combine_arrays` and `split_array` take 1d lists and operate on them. I can't figure out how to properly access these inner lists to pass to the functions. Specifically when I try to append to inner lists with `combine_arrays` it adds a reference to a list as opposed to the individual elements as desired.

```
sub assemble_groups { #(parent1, parent2, new group size)
    my $holder = 0;
    my $parent1 = shift;
    my $parent2 = shift;
    my $num_groups = shift;
    my $blocks = get_2d_agree_groups(\@{${$parent1}{'groups'}},\@{${$parent2}{'groups'}});
    my @disagree_block = pop @{$blocks}; 
    my $agree_size = @{$blocks};
    while($agree_size < $num_groups)
    {
        my $index = getrand(0,($agree_size-1));
        my $size = @{${$blocks}[$index]};
        my $split_index = getrand(0,($size-1));
        my $new_array = split_array(\@{${$blocks}[$index]},$split_index);
        push @{$blocks}, $new_array;
        $agree_size++;
    }
    while($agree_size > $num_groups)
    {
        my $join1 = getrand(0,($agree_size-1));
        my $join2 = getrand(0,($agree_size-1));
        while($join1==$join2)
        {
            $join2 = getrand(0,($agree_size-1));
        }
        my @hold = ${$blocks}[$join2];
        my $test = join('',@hold);
        splice @{$blocks}, $join2, 1;
        combine_arrays(\@{${$blocks}[$join1]},\@hold); #right here
        $agree_size--;
    }
    my $i=0;
    my $disagree_size = @disagree_block;
    while (($i<$agree_size) && $disagree_size)
    {
        getnewgroup(\@{${$blocks}[$i]},\@disagree_block);
        $disagree_size = @disagree_block;
        $i++;
    }
    if($disagree_size)
    {
        combine_arrays(\@{${$blocks}[$i-1]},\@disagree_block); #right here
    }
    return $blocks;
}
```

relevant functions:

```
sub combine_arrays { #(1d array 1, 1d array)
        my $group1 = shift;
        my $group2 = shift;
        my $group2_size = @{$group2};
        my $next = 0;
        for(my $i=0;$i<$group2_size;$i++)
        {
             $next = @{$group2}[$i];
             push @{$group1}, $next;
        }
}
sub split_array { #(array, index)
      my $old_array = shift;
      my $at = shift;
      my @new_array;
      my $old_size = @{$old_array};
      for(my $i=$at;$i<$old_size;$i++)
      {
           push @new_array, ${$old_array}[$at];
           splice @{$old_array}, $at, 1;
      }
      return \@new_array;
 }
```

Comment: What's a "list of list"? Do you mean an array of array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
my @hold = ${$blocks}[$join2];
```

is unreadable version of

```
my @hold = $blocks->[$join2];
```

so you might want to dereference the array,

```
my @hold = @{ $blocks->[$join2] };
```

*Side notes*:

- enable `strict` and `warnings` if you didn't already.
- `\@{${$blocks}[$join1]}` is taking reference to dereferenced array which is equal back to `${$blocks}[$join1]` (or `$blocks->[$join1]`)

Answer (score 1):

You do not need a combine_array function.  That's what [`push`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/push.html) is for.

The two calls to that function can be changed from

```
combine_arrays(\@{${$blocks}[$join1]},\@hold); #right here
...
combine_arrays(\@{${$blocks}[$i-1]},\@disagree_block); #right here
```

To just a call to `push`:

```
push @{$blocks->[$join1]}, @hold;
...    
push @{$blocks->[$i-1]}, @disagree_block;
```